# How to change and list a file containing lines with the following format : XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, tr

For example, let's say I have a file "athletes" with the lines

```
1995-05-30-John-Smith 
1992-John-30-Smith-10
```

How could I list the first 2 words of the lines that end in "Smith" and the last one, changing the format to # at the same time:

So the output would be:

```
1995#05#Smith
```

Comment: If you really want "lines that end in Smith", make sure you don't have any trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` like:

```
awk -F'-' '/Smith$/{print $1"#"$2"#"$NF}' athletes
```

It will give output:

```
1995#05#Smith
```

Here awk will search for the lines ending with `Smith`, and it will the print first, second and last field with `#`, in between them.

Using `sed`

```
sed -En 's/([^-]*)-([^-]*).*Smith$/\1#\2#Smith/gp' file.txt
```

It will match until first two `-` occurs, and then will print only matching lines after modifying them.

Comment: If I want to do for one more word for example ending in "Smith" or "William" is there anyway to do it in just one command?

Comment: @MADS you can use simple or condition, i.e.  use `/Smith$/ || /William$/` instead of `/Smith$/`. Tell me after using this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
grep "Smith$" file | tr "-" "#" | cut -d'#' -f1,2,5
```

Output:

```
1995#05#Smith
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it below by simple command too

```
 awk -F "-" '/Smith$/&&OFS="#"{print $1,$2,$NF}' file
```

output

```
1995#05#Smith
```

Comment: Why are you doing a variable assignment as part of the condition? I would define OFS as a command line argument with the `-v` switch.